# 408 Request Timeout, is it just me?

Tags: support, status-completed, 408-timeout

During the day, almost every day, I get a handful of `408 Request Timeout` pages when doing stuff on Stack Overflow or Meta Stack Overflow.

Is this an Australia thing, or are others experiencing this intermittently?

Comment: Same here, very occasionally (like 2-3 times in 14 days).

Comment: @Pekka, the thing is I get it on no other sites, so I blame haproxy or something

Comment: @waffles I've never seen it anywhere else than on SO and MSO (although I'm not entirely sure about the latter)

Comment: I get it on SO occasionally too, don't know that I've ever noticed it on meta (also in Sydney)

Comment: +1. I'm US-based and get this on SO periodically.  Thought it was just a bad connection on my part.

Comment: Happens around once a week over here..

Comment: Just saw several of them here (London, UK) - first ones ever. Looks like they happen when posting.

Comment: Get that error few times a week. I just hit F5 and it disapear.

Comment: @waffles - Are you seeing these again recently? I'm hitting them 10 - 15 times per day over the last two weeks.

Comment: @TimPost: I'm hitting them 20-25 times a day. Is there any progress? :)

Comment: @AmalMurali I'm seeing these far less often now, but I will take a look.

Comment: I've gotten a bunch of these today, from various different SE sites.

Comment: The same here, except that it is probably several times more worse than @Amal Murali mentioned

Answer (score 8):

We send our web logs to SQL so we can query them. It turns out that we have a bug that prevents 408s from being logged to SQL.

I did take several random samples of 10,000,000 requests each from our raw logs and have found ~ 30 per 10,000,000 requests that come through as 408. [HAProxy records termination states](http://cbonte.github.com/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#8.5), for all of them I have found they are logged as "cR--" which means:

```
c : the client-side timeout expired while waiting for the client to
            send or receive data.
R : the proxy was waiting for a complete, valid REQUEST from the client
            (HTTP mode only). Nothing was sent to any server.
```

Since 99.99972% of the requests sampled don't have this problem, for now I am going to regard these as a negligible error. If you are receiving a lot more of these over a long period of time (i.e. more that 30 for every 10 million requests you make) I think there is likely a client side issue.

However, since it is possible that my samples are missing spurts of 408s I will do more extensive research when our 408s are part of queryable logs (should be a week or two, the person who maintains our logging system is on vacation at the moment). I will also look closely at the IPs of people who are reporting the issue to see if I can get any more detail -- but right now it is hard with raw data due to the size of it.

**Update May 26, 2014:**
It is possible this related to [tcp-reconnect in modern browsers and our client timeout settings in haproxy.](http://blog.haproxy.com/2014/05/26/haproxy-and-http-errors-408-in-chrome/) I'm going to have our latest SRE member [Shane Madden](http://blog.serverfault.com/2014/04/23/welcome-serverfault-valued-associate-0000007/) investigate this now that I have a reasonable hypothesis.

**Update May 28, 2014:**
Shane has investigated and this should now be resolved for Chrome users, see answer on [408 Request Time-outs still continues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208790/408-request-time-outs-still-continues/232275#232275). Anyone else seeing these issues, let us know.

Comment: about a minute ago, here on meta.  IP 220.239.101.xxx

Comment: I've had this a lot recently, mostly when browsing on my iphone via 3G but occasionally on wifi. Only affects stackexchange sites and I've just had 3 in a row. My current IP address is 82.132.210.xxx

Comment: IP is 109.171.83.xx, a few minutes ago. Most of the time this is happening once every 4-10 minutes or so of active browsing. (Rarely it stops 408ing for an hour or two, though.) I guess, it is somehow related to the provider (overall connection here appears to be not very stable), however, there are no problems with other sites.

Comment: @Kyle, still get this every few days.  Just had it about 2 minutes ago on SO.  IP is 59.167.129.xxx

Comment: I saw several of these (2-3) yesterday and today, after months of no sightings. I'm on a 3G mobile connection (which is pretty stable though - I don't think that's the reason)

Comment: I have not seen this issue ever since the first router reboot. I suspect it is resolved now

Comment: @waffles: Just happened to me on 92.3.157.238 (everyone else: please don't DDOS my Netgear router :( :P )

Comment: yeah @Matt I thought it was over but got it again yesterday

Comment: I just got this error and my IP is 69.232.71.12.

Comment: I'd add that I see this ~6-7 times a week.

Comment: I got one of these right now on StackOverflow if you wanted something to go look for in your logs.

Comment: And another one right now when trying to view this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212605/adding-meta-tags-to-individual-posts-of-blogger

Comment: And another one right now accessing: http://stackoverflow.com/admin

Comment: You can tell me to stop ? :)

Comment: I get one whey trying to answer the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491808/how-to-compare-a-local-clob-column-against-a-clob-column-in-a-remote-database-ins

Comment: This only seems to happen if I post more than 22 lines of code in my answer.

Comment: I've been getting the same error for a while now too. I posted a [question here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208790/220538). Can you take a look? :)

Comment: I can report that I've been getting a *few* of these on SE, not too many though.

Comment: I've reproduced this and confirmed that at least the 408s that I'm getting are exactly what are being discussed in the HAProxy blog post. [Bug has been filed for Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=377581) and we'll be testing the suggested workaround within the next couple days.  Is anyone seeing these 408s consistently on a good internet connection, and not using Chrome?

Comment: This should now be resolved for Chrome users, see answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232275/167585). Anyone else seeing these issues, let us know.