# 408 Request Time-out

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [408 Request Timeout, is it just me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80432/408-request-timeout-is-it-just-me)

I am getting this error 50% of the times I try to access StackOverflow.
There is something wrong with my PC, connection or is it a stackoverflow problem?

[image]

Does anyone know where this erros is coming from? Is it provided by stackoverflow, Stack Exchange server or something else?

Comment: I'm not seeing this. How long has it been going on? If it's old, I assume it's just you because people usually come to Meta to complain about even 30-second outages.

Comment: it started this morning... when this error appears to me I just press F5 and the page loads... that's weird if the problem is just with me

Comment: Can you visit other Stack Exchange websites normally? How about non-Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome and this error appears only for stackoverflow... does anyone know the meaning of this error... I mean the error is provided by stackoverflow or something on the way, I mean between server and my pc?

Comment: Depending on how much detail you want, you might be interested in [the Wikipedia list of HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) or the official spec (which is linked to by the Wikipedia article).

Comment: This has been going on for over a year: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80432/408-request-timeout-is-it-just-me - I get the same one or twice a week.

Comment: @Kev - thanks for the link... I will check on that

Comment: This honestly only ever happens to me the first time I request a SE site for the day, and not always either.