# 408 Request Time-outs still continues

Tags: bug, status-completed, 408-timeout

I'm frequently getting `408 Request Time-out` errors  when browsing through Stack Overflow and Meta. I used to get this four or five times a day before, but now it has become very frequent. I've read [this February 2011 question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80432/220538) in which Kyle Brandt ♦ says:

> We send our web logs to SQL so we can query them. It turns out that we have a bug that prevents 408s from being logged to SQL. [...] I will do more extensive research when our 408s are part of queryable logs (should be a week or two [...]).

My internet connection is somewhat stable and I haven't experienced this issue on other sites before. I don't think it's a browser-specific issue as it is reproducible on latest versions of Google Chrome *and* Firefox (on Ubuntu 13.10). However, it is specific to Stack Overflow and Meta. I'm unable to reproduce this on other SE sites.

Am I the only one facing this issue? Could it be something wrong with the regional CDN or something like that? Could someone please take a look at this issue? ([not pointing hands](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80432/408-request-timeout-is-it-just-me#comment635504_80432))

This appears when I try to close-vote questions, too:

[image]

Comment: I have seen these more often since I've moved to a place with a less-than-perfect WLAN. It's not often enough for me to be annoying, though.

Comment: I see this sometimes, rarely, after a couple second delay on a bad connection.

Comment: I've seen that when I was having network issues, but never when my network connection works perfectly

Comment: I get that error regularly with weak edge mobile connections.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug in Stack Exchange or that there's anything the team can do, it's more likely local issue with your connection and/or ISP.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: What about [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80501/220538)?

Comment: @AmalMurali feel free to ping Kyle by posting comment on his answer, he still work for SE and still around. (well, 6 days ago so you might have to wait couple of days)

Comment: Upvoted: I hit this error twice this morning in quick succession, on my home cable modem connection which has been otherwise very stable this morning.

Comment: See also [Kyle's update](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80432/408-request-timeout-is-it-just-me/80501#80501): *"It is possible this related to [tcp-reconnect in modern browsers and our client timeout settings in haproxy](http://blog.haproxy.com/2014/05/26/haproxy-and-http-errors-408-in-chrome/). I'm going to have our latest SRE member [Shane Madden](http://blog.serverfault.com/2014/04/23/welcome-serverfault-valued-associate-0000007/) investigate this now that I have a reasonable hypothesis."*

Comment: Shane [is asking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80432/408-request-timeout-is-it-just-me/80501#comment764563_80501): *"Is anyone seeing these 408s consistently on a good internet connection, and not using Chrome?"*

Answer (score 5):

As far as we can tell, the recent reports of this are due to a Chrome update.

A client side timeout seems to have stopped working, which created a small window in which a 408 sent to close a speculative connection by the server was unintentionally read as the response when attempting to use the connection to send a request.

So, you would potentially get a 408 when you sent a request between 15 and 16 seconds after your most recent request.

We've filed a [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=377581) for Chrome, and implemented the workaround from HAProxy [here](http://blog.haproxy.com/2014/05/26/haproxy-and-http-errors-408-in-chrome/).

Let me know if anyone's still observing regular 408 errors.

Comment: From your bug report: *"[Chrome] will send the request after the 408 response has been sitting in the receive buffer, and use that 408 response as the apparent response to the request"*. Very nice find!