# What is 408 Time-out error and why only on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, 408-timeout

I've been facing this error since a lot of months now though it has been occurring annoyingly very often during last few days.

```
408 Request Time-out
Your browser didn't send a complete request in time.
```

I'm using Google Chrome on a Windows Server 2008 machine and have a fairly stable internet connection.
Never seen this error on any other website.

**What actually causes this error and is something wrong on my end?**

Comment: I'm getting the same error on http://github.com, but only with Internet Explorer 11 from time to time. Never had it on SO - not with any browser. Also I don't know your case, but in my case the whole thing appears within milliseconds, so it's not like a long timeout.

Comment: Mario stackoverflow replies average ~300ms if I ping, and displays that quickly when it does. Actually it shows timeout error also within milliseconds.

Comment: Related - [408 Request Timeout, is it just me?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80432)

Comment: I've run into this issue on Github and SO when there's a proxy server between me and the sites.